# How do I pass name props from BottomTabs to Stack.Screen headerTitle?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5

I want to pass the name of the current tab to screen's headerTitle. This is a type of setup that I got from the reactnavigation.org website.  This is my code setup.

```
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
```

These are my Tabs.

```
function Tabs() {
    const { colors } = useTheme();
    const theme = useTheme();
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Home"
            activeTintColor='#fff'
        >
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={Home}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
                    tabBarColor: colors.tab,
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                        <Ionicons name="ios-home" color={color} size={26} />
                    ),
                    tabBarBadge: 5,
                }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Profile"
                component={Profile}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
                    tabBarColor: colors.tab,
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                        <Ionicons name="ios-person" color={color} size={26} />
                    ),
                }}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}
```

This is my Stack. I found a line of code on the website which shows passing props to the screen's option, like `options={{ headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} /> }}`. I tried the something similar - replaced `LogoTitle` with `Tabs` - and I got an error saying `Error: Another navigator is already registered for this container.`

```
function AppTabs() {
    const { colors } = useTheme();
    const theme = useTheme();
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: colors.tab,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }}
        >
            <Stack.Screen
                name="Tabs"
                component={Tabs}
                options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                    headerLeft: () => (
                        <Icon.Button
                            name="ios-menu"
                            size={25}
                            backgroundColor={colors.tab}
                            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
                        >

                        </Icon.Button>
                    ),
                    // Pass tab name when tab is pressed, here!

                })}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
                name="Contacts"
                component={Phone}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
                name="ContactProfile"
                component={ContactProfile}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>

    )
}

export default AppTabs;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute` function for this:

```
// Import getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute
import {
  NavigationContainer,
  getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute,
} from '@react-navigation/native';

function getHeaderTitle(route) {
  // In case the focused route is not found, assume it's the first screen
  return getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? 'Home';
}

function AppTabs() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Tabs"
        component={Tabs}
        options={({route}) => ({
          title: getHeaderTitle(route),
        })}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Contacts" component={Phone} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ContactProfile" component={ContactProfile} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

You can read more about it in the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state